# Как автоматически добавлять объекты ForeignKey в объект модели Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, django, api

Есть система, которая через API тянет данные с AmoCRM, нужно заполнять объекты сделки внутри системы, данными из API.

Есть например поле: `main_contact = models.ForeignKey(Main_contact, on_delete = models.CASCADE)`

Заполнить его данными с ответа, я могу, но этих полей в ответе может быть несколько к одной сделке, как правильно привязать несколько контактов к сделке? Для сохранения данных в объект использую метод `update_or_created()`

Comment: Создавайте отдельно объекты `Main_contact`, используйте метод `obj, created = update_or_create( ... )`, затем `obj.main_contact.add( obj1, obj2, obj3 )` где obj1, obj2, obj3 - объекты модели Main_contact.

Comment: А как узнать их порядок/номер? Чтобы привязывать нужные контакты к нужным сделкам? Система синхронизируется ежедневно, и в одном ответе, может идти до 500 сделок, где будет разное количество контактов. Как отследить именно эту привязку?

Comment: Понял, затупил сильно просматривая Ваш комментарий, прошу простить, почти вторые сутки без сна.